# Why does my query to a populated SharePoint list return a count of zero?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-online, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to develop a SharePoint add in using VS 2022 Community. In it, I query a populated list, but the query returns a count of zero, though the ListItemCollection says that data are available.. I also tried to query all the lists on the site to see if it was just my list; some returned data, and some did not. What am I doing wrong? Here is a code snippet.

```
               if (clientContext != null)
                {

                    spUser = clientContext.Web.CurrentUser;

                    clientContext.Load(spUser, user => user.Title);

                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    ViewBag.UserName = spUser.Title;
                    // Get the CiviCRM access data
                    SP.Site theSite = clientContext.Site;
                    SP.Web theWeb = clientContext.Web;
                    clientContext.Load(theWeb);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
 
                    SP.List CiviCRMList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
                    SP.CamlQuery theQuery = SP.CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(100);
                    SP.ListItemCollection itemCollection = CiviCRMList.GetItems(theQuery);

                    // Retrieve all items in the ListItemCollection from List.GetItems(Query).
                    clientContext.Load(itemCollection);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    foreach (SP. ListItem listItem in itemCollection)
                    {
                        string theTitle = listItem["Title"].ToString(); 
                    }
```

Comment: Why "query returns a count of zero, though the ListItemCollection says that data are available"?  Put a break point in the code and try to determine the inconsistencies.

Comment: Tried breakpoints, tried examining the various lists and couldn't see what it might be. I wondered if someone else had seen the issue.

Comment: The database isn't returning anything.  If there was a WHERE is you query I usually recommend running without the WHERE.  Looks like you are returning all the data.  You are not getting any exception.  Which means your connection is completing.   But the database table is empty.  Normally this happens when you are connecting to the wrong database.  I would check the connection string to make sure you are connecting to the correct database.

Comment: The query is empty. Querying every list in on the site reveals a mismatch between the number of items the list data reports and the number returned in the listitemcollection, even for those lists where some are returned. I am not using a connection string, but a client context variable, and querying the lists by name returns the list I have created and am trying to query.

Comment: Sounds like you are not emptying the list so each time you query you are adding new data to the existing list.

Comment: Strange - what I am seeing is that there are fewer entries in the listitemcollection than the item count in the list, not more. If I wasn't emptying the list before each query, surely I would see more items, not less? What has triggered this query is that just querying a single list returns no item, despite there being an item in the list.

Comment: That make sense.  itemCollection is every thing while itemCollection is result of the query which may contain a WHERE that filters the data.

Comment: There is no WHERE clause in the query, just: 

SP.CamlQuery theQuery = SP.CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(100)

So, why are not items returned?

Comment: What type of database are you using?  Are servers linked.  Check connection string you may be using wrong Server or Database on Server.  A Server can have more than one database.

Comment: I am querying SharePoint Online lists, so not interacting with a database directly. The issue is with getting data from SharePoint lists programmatically.

Comment: The share point is a two port application.  First port is server to database.  Second port is a client to server connection.  The code posted looks like Entity interface which is the first port,  So any data returned from the database the server has to take the received data from Port One and Send on Port two.

Comment: I wrote code to query every list on the site and tried to put the results in this comment, but I can't format them, so gave up trying to display them here. The only lists that returned results were hidden ones; the visible ones, despite having data in them returned collection counts of zero. I thought the client context was connecting the lists, and am puzzled by how the server is supposed to send data to port 2.

Comment: You have to write the software to send/receive data through the two ports.  Each port is a connection.  The port from server to database is handled in Entity.  The port from client to server is an HTTP connection where client sends a request and server sends a response.  The server response basically takes the data from the entity classes and passes results to client.  At server, the request from client sends a query to the database and the results of query is data in the entity classes.

Comment: I am still puzzled. Do you have sample code? Basically, I am using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client to connect to SharePoint and do the necessary lookups. List.GetItems returns data from some hidden lists, but not from 'normal' lists. I am using a VS 2022 SharePoint App template. If List.GetItems doesn't work, then the SharePoint template is pretty useless, isn't it?

Comment: Your server has to do work.  The data received from client has to be modified to meet the database requirements.  The server is a two sided interface and what comes in one interface may need to be modified.  You are designing the server and you have to decide what is the easiest method to complete the task.  You may want to modify the client-server interface to make it more compatible with the server database interface so the server would do less work.  But that is your choice.  You are the designer, not me.